# iCloud email - server password changed?

Tags: icloud, email, password, hacking

I have been using iCloud for a few months now with no problems until today.

My mobile flagged up that I cannot login to my iCloud email account due to:

Server password has been changed. Input the changed password.

I didn't change any passwords. Can someone help point me in the right direction of where I can find help please?

Comment: fwiw I experienced an iCloud server outage just moments ago. You might just wait a bit and try again. It seems to be working for me now.

Comment: Servers also aren't working for me, but official status report shows nothing: http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

Answer (score 1):

I just contacted Apple Support and they confirmed this was a new Apple ID authentication issue. Basically, iCloud has deemed that my account should not just have one password, but a dual-verification which, once completed, generates app-specific passwords for each device used (Apple devices or not).

- Two-step verification for Apple ID
- Using app-specific passwords

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like someone stole your password, logged himself in the service using your password and then changed the old password to a new one.

Did you get an Email, which reads that your password has been changed? If you got one, there should be the option to reset the password and/or call support. Do both.

If you haven't got an Email, get in touch with Apple Support and explain them your problem, they will know what to do.
Here you can contact Apple Support: https://getsupport.apple.com/ServiceOptionAction.action

I don't suppose to reset the password yourself, since you probably got hacked, which is an official crime, so you should tell Apple about it.

To prevent such an event in the future, use strong passwords containing letters AND numbers. Never use the same password for two different websites or services.
You can find a list with the most popular passwords here(Don't use them!!): http://gizmodo.com/the-25-most-popular-passwords-of-2014-were-all-doomed-1680596951